# Wrong characters in JFrame title

Tags: java, swing, utf-8, character-encoding, jframe

When I write something like this:

```
...
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
...
myFrame.setTitle("\t\t myApp");
```

I get the result below in the JFrame title:

[image]

It just happens in Windows XP and works fine in Leopard OS. Is there any way to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Just use spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: BTW - in lieu of a question, I presumed it to be 'how to fix this?'.

Comment: @Dan I know that but I would like to know if there is any way to use no-alphanumeric characters in the title on windows.

Comment: As I read this question I got another question. Is it possible to determine the number of space characters used by the current system tab? If it is possible and it is important for him to use tabs in the title he could simply replace each tab with the number of spaces it takes.

Comment: @ka3ak is there even a system-wide tab width? I don't think so, and I don't think there should be one.

Comment: @JacobRaihle Yes. I agree. The representation of a TAB is different. But when he uses it in myFrame.setTitle("\t\t myApp"); then he expects some length of the TAB right? Probably the length of the TAB printed in console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Andrew has already pointed, you should not be doing this.  Essentially Windows went to the font's character dictionary to find out how best to render "\t" and printed that wonderful square for you instead, cause that's all it knew how to do.

The title is not a "text component", it's a rendered element, and thus, doesn't handle formatting of this nature...

Follow Andrew's advice

Answer (score 3):

> When I do something like this:

The fix is not to do that.  Your app. is not so special that it deserves to have the name 'indented'.

Comment: more than a little condescending Andrew ;)